# How to set environmental variable in another env file in development and production environment?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, environment-variables

I want to use another .env file in development and production.
For production build, I use `npm run build:production` and for development, I use `npm run start`.
But I didn't use environment variable.
In my project, env file is not used now. so when I build project, I should change some code. 
I want to use env file.

ex:

- development environment

  npm run dev
- production environment

  npm run prod

development:
**.env.dev**

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

production:
**.dnv.prod**

```
BASE_URL=https://aaa.com
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --progress --config webpack.config.ts",
    "build:production": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
}
```

webpack.config.ts

```
const config = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './src/index.tsx',
        './assets/styles/main.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.css', '.scss', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Hubbers v2',
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html')
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin('main.css'),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: 'assets/images', to: 'images'},
            {from: 'assets/icons', to: 'icons'},
            {from: 'src/_redirects', to: ''}
        ]),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /moment[/\\]locale$/,
            /eu|cn/
        )
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|webp|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|otf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)/,
                use: ['css-hot-loader', ...ExtractTextWebpackPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                includePaths: [...require('bourbon').includePaths, ...require('bourbon-neat').includePaths]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loaders: [
                    'react-hot-loader/webpack',
                    'awesome-typescript-loader'
                ],
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
export default config
```

Comment: Have a look at dotenv and their [path option](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack). It supports specifying the path parameter. You can set the path parameter by env variable (sound ironic- to load ENV variables, you need an ENV variable...).

So you need to add `path` parameter to `Dotenv` constructor and set file depending on `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable:

```js
{
    plugins: [
        new  new Dotenv({
            path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.dnv.prod' : '.env.dev'
        })
    ]
}
```

Then you need update your scripts to add NODE_ENV variable to webpack ([documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)):

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=development --progress --config webpack.config.ts",
        "build:production": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=production -p --progress --config webpack.config.ts",
    }
}
```